# Using node-media-server and FFMPEG, Transmuxing ends when rtmp is publishing with no errors

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I've configured and used [node-media-server](https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server) library on 2 of my test servers and it works great, but when I'm trying to make it work on production, it creates directories for different qualities, but does not generate .ts and .m3u8 for them. It only creates original hls outputs.
My logs show that instantly after `[rtmp publish] Handle video.` and `[rtmp publish] Handle audio.` files, it receives `[rtmp publish] Close stream. id=Y8KK9U3D streamPath=/live/15_1280 streamId=1` and `[rtmp play] Close stream. id=7MC9Q65N streamPath=/live/15_1280 streamId=1`
Please note that everything is the same on my test and prod servers, and with no known cause, it fails on some of my servers and works on some other ones. I've tried both deploying dockerized and not dockerized versions, with different node versions.
FFMPEG version is also the same on all systems.

My configs:

```
const config = {
    rtmp: {
        port: parseInt(process.env.STREAM_RTMP_PORT || '8082'),
        chunk_size: parseInt(process.env.STREAM_CHUNK_SIZE || '60000'),
        gop_cache: true,
        ping: 60,
        ping_timeout: 30
    },
    http: {
        mediaroot: process.env.FILE_PATH + '/media',
        port: parseInt(process.env.STREAM_HTTP_PORT || '8081'),
        allow_origin: '*'
    },
    auth: process.env.STREAM_SECRET?.length ? {
        api: true,
        play: false,
        publish: true,
        secret: process.env.STREAM_SECRET,
        api_user: process.env.STREAM_API_AUTH_USER,
        api_pass: process.env.STREAM_API_AUTH_PASS,
    } : undefined,
    trans: {
        ffmpeg: process.env.FFMPEG_PATH || '',
        tasks: [
            {
                app: 'live',

                hls: true,
                hlsFlags: '[hls_time=2:hls_list_size=3:hls_flags=delete_segments]',
                hlsKeep: true, // to prevent hls file delete after end the stream

                // dash: true,
                // dashFlags: '[f=dash:window_size=3:extra_window_size=5]',
                // dashKeep: true, // to prevent dash file delete after end the stream

                mp4: true,
                mp4Flags: '[movflags=frag_keyframe+empty_moov]',
            }
        ]
    },
    fission: {
        ffmpeg: process.env.FFMPEG_PATH || '',
        tasks: [
            {
                rule: "live/*",
                model: [
                    {
                        ab: "128k",
                        vb: "1500k",
                        vs: "720x1280",
                        vf: "30",
                    },
                    {
                        ab: "64k",
                        vb: "1000k",
                        vs: "480x854",
                        vf: "24",
                    },
                    {
                        ab: "32k",
                        vb: "600k",
                        vs: "360x640",
                        vf: "20",
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

and logs:

```
[NodeEvent on preConnect] id=OKRRCRT1 args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","supportsGoAway":true,"flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)","swfUrl":"rtmp://IP_PORT_HERE/live","tcUrl":"rtmp://IP_PORT_HERE/live"}
7/5/2023 16:13:28 963 [INFO] [rtmp connect] id=OKRRCRT1 ip=MY_IP_HERE app=live args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","supportsGoAway":true,"flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)","swfUrl":"rtmp://IP_PORT_HERE/live","tcUrl":"rtmp://IP_PORT_HERE/live"}
[NodeEvent on postConnect] id=OKRRCRT1 args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","supportsGoAway":true,"flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)","swfUrl":"rtmp://IP_PORT_HERE/live","tcUrl":"rtmp://IP_PORT_HERE/live"}
[NodeEvent on prePublish] id=OKRRCRT1 StreamPath=/live/15 args={"sign":"CORRECT_SIGN_HERE__REMOVED_TO_SHARE_IT_WITH_YOU"}
7/5/2023 16:13:28 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] New stream. id=OKRRCRT1 streamPath=/live/15 streamId=1
[NodeEvent on postPublish] id=OKRRCRT1 StreamPath=/live/15 args={"sign":"CORRECT_SIGN_HERE__REMOVED_TO_SHARE_IT_WITH_YOU"}
7/5/2023 16:13:28 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing MP4] /live/15 to /home/data/stream_files/media/live/15/2023-07-05-16-13-28.mp4
7/5/2023 16:13:28 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing HLS] /live/15 to /home/data/stream_files/media/live/15/index.m3u8
[NodeEvent on preConnect] id=CPRQV6U6 args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
7/5/2023 16:13:28 963 [INFO] [rtmp connect] id=CPRQV6U6 ip=::ffff:127.0.0.1 app=live args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on postConnect] id=CPRQV6U6 args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on preConnect] id=FTAZ3SW8 args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
7/5/2023 16:13:28 963 [INFO] [rtmp connect] id=FTAZ3SW8 ip=::ffff:127.0.0.1 app=live args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on postConnect] id=FTAZ3SW8 args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on prePlay] id=CPRQV6U6 StreamPath=/live/15 args={}
[NodeEvent on postPlay] id=CPRQV6U6 StreamPath=/live/15 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:28 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Join stream. id=CPRQV6U6 streamPath=/live/15  streamId=1 
[NodeEvent on prePlay] id=FTAZ3SW8 StreamPath=/live/15 args={}
[NodeEvent on postPlay] id=FTAZ3SW8 StreamPath=/live/15 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:28 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Join stream. id=FTAZ3SW8 streamPath=/live/15  streamId=1 
7/5/2023 16:13:29 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Handle audio. id=OKRRCRT1 streamPath=/live/15 sound_format=10 sound_type=2 sound_size=1 sound_rate=3 codec_name=AAC 48000 2ch
7/5/2023 16:13:29 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Handle video. id=OKRRCRT1 streamPath=/live/15 frame_type=1 codec_id=7 codec_name=H264 1920x1080
[NodeEvent on preConnect] id=ISVLTK71 args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
7/5/2023 16:13:30 963 [INFO] [rtmp connect] id=ISVLTK71 ip=::ffff:127.0.0.1 app=live args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
[NodeEvent on postConnect] id=ISVLTK71 args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
[NodeEvent on prePublish] id=ISVLTK71 StreamPath=/live/15_1280 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:30 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] New stream. id=ISVLTK71 streamPath=/live/15_1280 streamId=1
[NodeEvent on postPublish] id=ISVLTK71 StreamPath=/live/15_1280 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:30 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing MP4] /live/15_1280 to /home/data/stream_files/media/live/15_1280/2023-07-05-16-13-30.mp4
7/5/2023 16:13:30 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing HLS] /live/15_1280 to /home/data/stream_files/media/live/15_1280/index.m3u8
[NodeEvent on preConnect] id=YNOFQB7P args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp connect] id=YNOFQB7P ip=::ffff:127.0.0.1 app=live args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
[NodeEvent on postConnect] id=YNOFQB7P args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
[NodeEvent on preConnect] id=OT8T2OPP args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp connect] id=OT8T2OPP ip=::ffff:127.0.0.1 app=live args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on postConnect] id=OT8T2OPP args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on prePublish] id=YNOFQB7P StreamPath=/live/15_854 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] New stream. id=YNOFQB7P streamPath=/live/15_854 streamId=1
[NodeEvent on postPublish] id=YNOFQB7P StreamPath=/live/15_854 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing MP4] /live/15_854 to /home/data/stream_files/media/live/15_854/2023-07-05-16-13-31.mp4
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing HLS] /live/15_854 to /home/data/stream_files/media/live/15_854/index.m3u8
[NodeEvent on prePlay] id=OT8T2OPP StreamPath=/live/15_1280 args={}
[NodeEvent on postPlay] id=OT8T2OPP StreamPath=/live/15_1280 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Join stream. id=OT8T2OPP streamPath=/live/15_1280  streamId=1 
[NodeEvent on preConnect] id=62KCI105 args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp connect] id=62KCI105 ip=::ffff:127.0.0.1 app=live args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on postConnect] id=62KCI105 args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on preConnect] id=9QAHATOC args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp connect] id=9QAHATOC ip=::ffff:127.0.0.1 app=live args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
[NodeEvent on postConnect] id=9QAHATOC args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
[NodeEvent on prePlay] id=62KCI105 StreamPath=/live/15_854 args={}
[NodeEvent on postPlay] id=62KCI105 StreamPath=/live/15_854 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Join stream. id=62KCI105 streamPath=/live/15_854  streamId=1 
[NodeEvent on prePublish] id=9QAHATOC StreamPath=/live/15_640 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] New stream. id=9QAHATOC streamPath=/live/15_640 streamId=1
[NodeEvent on postPublish] id=9QAHATOC StreamPath=/live/15_640 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing MP4] /live/15_640 to /home/data/stream_files/media/live/15_640/2023-07-05-16-13-31.mp4
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing HLS] /live/15_640 to /home/data/stream_files/media/live/15_640/index.m3u8
[NodeEvent on preConnect] id=V308RJRW args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp connect] id=V308RJRW ip=::ffff:127.0.0.1 app=live args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on postConnect] id=V308RJRW args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on prePlay] id=V308RJRW StreamPath=/live/15_640 args={}
[NodeEvent on postPlay] id=V308RJRW StreamPath=/live/15_640 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:31 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Join stream. id=V308RJRW streamPath=/live/15_640  streamId=1 
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Handle video. id=ISVLTK71 streamPath=/live/15_1280 frame_type=1 codec_id=7 codec_name=H264 720x1280
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Handle audio. id=ISVLTK71 streamPath=/live/15_1280 sound_format=10 sound_type=2 sound_size=1 sound_rate=3 codec_name=AAC 48000 2ch
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Close stream. id=ISVLTK71 streamPath=/live/15_1280 streamId=1
[NodeEvent on donePublish] id=ISVLTK71 StreamPath=/live/15_1280 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Close stream. id=OT8T2OPP streamPath=/live/15_1280 streamId=1
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp disconnect] id=OT8T2OPP
[NodeEvent on doneConnect] id=OT8T2OPP args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Handle video. id=YNOFQB7P streamPath=/live/15_854 frame_type=1 codec_id=7 codec_name=H264 480x854
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Handle audio. id=YNOFQB7P streamPath=/live/15_854 sound_format=10 sound_type=2 sound_size=1 sound_rate=3 codec_name=AAC 48000 2ch
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Close stream. id=YNOFQB7P streamPath=/live/15_854 streamId=1
[NodeEvent on donePublish] id=YNOFQB7P StreamPath=/live/15_854 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Close stream. id=62KCI105 streamPath=/live/15_854 streamId=1
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp disconnect] id=62KCI105
[NodeEvent on doneConnect] id=62KCI105 args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Close stream. id=9QAHATOC streamPath=/live/15_640 streamId=1
[NodeEvent on donePublish] id=9QAHATOC StreamPath=/live/15_640 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Close stream. id=V308RJRW streamPath=/live/15_640 streamId=1
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp disconnect] id=V308RJRW
[NodeEvent on doneConnect] id=V308RJRW args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
[NodeEvent on donePlay] id=CPRQV6U6 StreamPath=/live/15 args={}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Close stream. id=CPRQV6U6 streamPath=/live/15 streamId=1
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp disconnect] id=CPRQV6U6
[NodeEvent on doneConnect] id=CPRQV6U6 args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing end] /live/15_1280
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp disconnect] id=ISVLTK71
[NodeEvent on doneConnect] id=ISVLTK71 args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing end] /live/15_640
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing end] /live/15_854
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp disconnect] id=9QAHATOC
[NodeEvent on doneConnect] id=9QAHATOC args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [rtmp disconnect] id=YNOFQB7P
[NodeEvent on doneConnect] id=YNOFQB7P args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; Lavf59.27.100)","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live"}
7/5/2023 16:13:32 963 [INFO] [Fission end] /live/15
7/5/2023 16:13:46 963 [INFO] [rtmp publish] Close stream. id=OKRRCRT1 streamPath=/live/15 streamId=1
[NodeEvent on donePublish] id=OKRRCRT1 StreamPath=/live/15 args={"sign":"CORRECT_SIGN_HERE__REMOVED_TO_SHARE_IT_WITH_YOU"}
7/5/2023 16:13:46 963 [INFO] [rtmp disconnect] id=OKRRCRT1
[NodeEvent on doneConnect] id=OKRRCRT1 args={"app":"live","type":"nonprivate","supportsGoAway":true,"flashVer":"FMLE/3.0 (compatible; FMSc/1.0)","swfUrl":"rtmp://IP_PORT_HERE/live","tcUrl":"rtmp://IP_PORT_HERE/live"}
7/5/2023 16:13:46 963 [INFO] [rtmp play] Close stream. id=FTAZ3SW8 streamPath=/live/15 streamId=1
7/5/2023 16:13:46 963 [INFO] [rtmp disconnect] id=FTAZ3SW8
[NodeEvent on doneConnect] id=FTAZ3SW8 args={"app":"live","flashVer":"LNX 9,0,124,2","tcUrl":"rtmp://127.0.0.1:PORT_HERE/live","fpad":false,"capabilities":15,"audioCodecs":4071,"videoCodecs":252,"videoFunction":1}
7/5/2023 16:13:46 963 [INFO] [Transmuxing end] /live/15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `logType: 4` to config and after checking FFmpeg logs and the flows, I found that the problem was that fission was not working correctly.
To solve the problem, I added `-threads 1` to fission's ffmpeg command. A quick workaround can be forking the project and adding `'-threads', '1'` to the `argv` array in the `node_fission_session.js` file.
I'm not aware what causes this issue on my machines yet, because the hardwares were totally similar!